# Twice of Github "checkout" action seems to reflect older version

Tags: github, amazon-s3, synchronization, action, checkout

I'm trying to perform following tasks, successively in my GitHub Actions workflow:

1. Downloading files using **`curl`**
2. Pushing the downloaded files
3. Syncing with an S3 bucket

While the workflow seems to work, it reflects an older version of the files. You can find my YAML file [here](https://github.com/jungle-escape/jungle-escape/blob/main/.github/workflows/deploy-core.yml).

The specific job causing the problem is available [here](https://github.com/jungle-escape/jungle-escape/actions/runs/7890348069). You can see the diff for two commits of the job [here](https://github.com/jungle-escape/jungle-escape/compare/7b31dc48c643b49503da84f8e691a95cca0f95ee..dd4e5fd8dbccab07301fef7ada2904a04245845d).

It's evident that the S3 bucket reflects the older commit (7b31dc4) rather than the newer one (dd4e5fd).

I'd appreciate any help in identifying if there's something I've overlooked. Thanks!

Comment: Found an issue with some help: the checkout in the first job doesn't stick in the next one. Tossed both jobs together, and it did the trick.